# Using "SaveAs" in a script in PaintShop Pro

Tags: python

I'm trying to automate some image editing tasks on PaintShop Pro. Simply put I want to manually load an image into PSP from its current location and then run a script on the image to resize, then canvas resize and finally save the resulting file with a new name (interactively) in its **original** location.

My existing script is as follows:

```py
from PSPApp import *

def ScriptProperties():
    return {
        'Author': u'',
        'Copyright': u'',
        'Description': u'',
        'Host': u'PaintShop Pro',
        'Host Version': u'21.00'
        }

def Do(Environment):
    # EnableOptimizedScriptUndo
    App.Do( Environment, 'EnableOptimizedScriptUndo', {
            'GeneralSettings': {
                'ExecutionMode': App.Constants.ExecutionMode.Default, 
                'AutoActionMode': App.Constants.AutoActionMode.Match, 
                'Version': ((21,0,0),1)
                }
            })

    # Resize
    App.Do( Environment, 'Resize', {
            'AspectRatio': 0.997183, 
            'CurrentDimensionUnits': App.Constants.UnitsOfMeasure.Pixels, 
            'CurrentResolutionUnits': App.Constants.ResolutionUnits.PixelsPerIn, 
            'Height': 251, 
            'MaintainAspectRatio': True, 
            'Resample': True, 
            'ResampleType': App.Constants.ResampleType.Bicubic, 
            'ResizeAllLayers': True, 
            'Resolution': 499, 
            'Width': 250, 
            'SharpnessValue': 50, 
            'AdvancedMode': True, 
            'ResizeType': 0, 
            'OneSide_Type': 0, 
            'OneSide_LongWidth': 657, 
            'OneSide_ShortHeight': 655, 
            'OneSide_Unit': App.Constants.UnitsOfMeasure.Pixels, 
            'OneSide_Active': 0, 
            'GeneralSettings': {
                'ExecutionMode': App.Constants.ExecutionMode.Default, 
                'AutoActionMode': App.Constants.AutoActionMode.Match, 
                'Version': ((21,0,0),1)
                }
            })

    # ResizeCanvas
    App.Do( Environment, 'ResizeCanvas', {
            'AspectRatio': 0.996016, 
            'FillColor': (9,7,10), 
            'HoriPlace': App.Constants.HorizontalType.Center, 
            'MaintainAspect': False, 
            'NewDimUnits': App.Constants.UnitsOfMeasure.Pixels, 
            'NewHeight': 250, 
            'NewWidth': 250, 
            'PlaceBottom': -1, 
            'PlaceLeft': 0, 
            'PlaceRight': 0, 
            'PlaceTop': 0, 
            'VertPlace': App.Constants.VerticalType.Center, 
            'GeneralSettings': {
                'ExecutionMode': App.Constants.ExecutionMode.Default, 
                'AutoActionMode': App.Constants.AutoActionMode.Match, 
                'Version': ((21,0,0),1)
                }
            })

    # FileSaveAs
    App.Do( Environment, 'FileSaveAs', {
            'Encoding': {
                'JPG': {
                    'Variant': App.Constants.JpegFormat.Lossless, 
                    'CompressionFactor': 20, 
                    'ChromaSubSampling': App.Constants.ChromaSubSampling.YCC_1x1_1x1_1x1, 
                    'EXIF': True, 
                    'EmbedJPGICC': True
                    }
                }, 
            'FileName': u'00.jpg', 
            'FileFormat': App.Constants.FileFormat.JPG, 
            'FormatDesc': u'JPG JPEG ', 
            'WorkingMode': 0, 
            'GeneralSettings': {
                'ExecutionMode': App.Constants.ExecutionMode.Interactive, 
                'AutoActionMode': App.Constants.AutoActionMode.PromoteAsk, 
                'Version': ((21,0,0),1)
                }, 
            'DefaultProperties': []
            })
```

This is all fine until I get to the `FileSaveAs` step. The current script saves the file to the current working directory for the **script**, rather than the directory for the **image file** I'm processing. (Note: I have the mode set to Interactive, so I have the opportunity to rename the file in an interactive SaveAs dialogue box).

Any help will be gratefully received. I'm very much a novice when it comes to scripting!

Update!
I worked out a solution to my original question by adding

```
path = App.TargetDocument.Name.rstrip(App.TargetDocument.Title)
    filename = path + "00_" + App.TargetDocument.Title
```

so that the new script is this ...

```py
from PSPApp import *

def ScriptProperties():
    return {
        'Author': u'',
        'Copyright': u'',
        'Description': u'',
        'Host': u'PaintShop Pro',
        'Host Version': u'21.00'
        }

def Do(Environment):
    path = App.TargetDocument.Name.rstrip(App.TargetDocument.Title)
    filename = path + "00_" + App.TargetDocument.Title
    # EnableOptimizedScriptUndo
    App.Do( Environment, 'EnableOptimizedScriptUndo', {
            'GeneralSettings': {
                'ExecutionMode': App.Constants.ExecutionMode.Default, 
                'AutoActionMode': App.Constants.AutoActionMode.Match, 
                'Version': ((21,0,0),1)
                }
            })

    # Resize
    App.Do( Environment, 'Resize', {
            'AspectRatio': 0.997183, 
            'CurrentDimensionUnits': App.Constants.UnitsOfMeasure.Pixels, 
            'CurrentResolutionUnits': App.Constants.ResolutionUnits.PixelsPerIn, 
            'Height': 251, 
            'MaintainAspectRatio': True, 
            'Resample': True, 
            'ResampleType': App.Constants.ResampleType.Bicubic, 
            'ResizeAllLayers': True, 
            'Resolution': 499, 
            'Width': 250, 
            'SharpnessValue': 50, 
            'AdvancedMode': True, 
            'ResizeType': 0, 
            'OneSide_Type': 0, 
            'OneSide_LongWidth': 657, 
            'OneSide_ShortHeight': 655, 
            'OneSide_Unit': App.Constants.UnitsOfMeasure.Pixels, 
            'OneSide_Active': 0, 
            'GeneralSettings': {
                'ExecutionMode': App.Constants.ExecutionMode.Default, 
                'AutoActionMode': App.Constants.AutoActionMode.Match, 
                'Version': ((21,0,0),1)
                }
            })

    # ResizeCanvas
    App.Do( Environment, 'ResizeCanvas', {
            'AspectRatio': 0.996016, 
            'FillColor': (9,7,10), 
            'HoriPlace': App.Constants.HorizontalType.Center, 
            'MaintainAspect': False, 
            'NewDimUnits': App.Constants.UnitsOfMeasure.Pixels, 
            'NewHeight': 250, 
            'NewWidth': 250, 
            'PlaceBottom': -1, 
            'PlaceLeft': 0, 
            'PlaceRight': 0, 
            'PlaceTop': 0, 
            'VertPlace': App.Constants.VerticalType.Center, 
            'GeneralSettings': {
                'ExecutionMode': App.Constants.ExecutionMode.Default, 
                'AutoActionMode': App.Constants.AutoActionMode.Match, 
                'Version': ((21,0,0),1)
                }
            })

    # FileSaveAs
    App.Do( Environment, 'FileSaveAs', {
            'Encoding': {
                'JPG': {
                    'Variant': App.Constants.JpegFormat.Lossless, 
                    'CompressionFactor': 0, 
                    'ChromaSubSampling': App.Constants.ChromaSubSampling.YCC_1x1_1x1_1x1, 
                    'EXIF': True, 
                    'EmbedJPGICC': True
                    }
                }, 
            'FileName': filename, 
            'FileFormat': App.Constants.FileFormat.JPG, 
            'FormatDesc': u'JPG JPEG ', 
            'WorkingMode': 0, 
            'GeneralSettings': {
                'ExecutionMode': App.Constants.ExecutionMode.Default, 
                'AutoActionMode': App.Constants.AutoActionMode.Match, 
                'Version': ((23,0,0),1)
                }, 
            'DefaultProperties': []
            })
```

I have a supplementary question now that perhaps someone could advise me on. To make the above script run without the need for my interaction (to rename the file) I would like to find a way the rename the file to be saved according to a template. In the above script I am already adding "00_" to the front of the original  filename but I would also like to remove any numeric characters from the end of the original filename. For example, I would like Landscape1.jpg or Landscape22.jpg or Landscape333.jpg etc. to be saved as 00_Landscape.jpg ... Any ideas?

Comment: Would there be a way to use `resub` and `isnumeric()` in some way to achieve this rename objective?

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest some variations to your strategy.
Please see the code that I use. In this code, Paintshop Pro would give a name like `Image1.jpg`, etc. Also, you can control all of the process from the text editor because in the long run it's easier and faster. I haven't included an interactive mode, but let's start with this and see how you like it :-)
I also deleted a lot of the Paintshop Pro code because it's easier to read and it still works fine. I just tried it to make sure and it's ok.

```
from PSPApp import *

def ScriptProperties(): return { }

def Do(Environment):

    # do the math for the crop
    size_height = 1000
    size_width = 500

    crop_height = 500
    crop_width = 250
    place_bottom = 250 
    place_left =  125
    place_right =  125
    place_top = 250

    
    # assign a variable to the folder containing your file eg:
    #insert path here:
    source_path = u'C:\\photos\\flowers\\flower1\\' # your original file is here
    source_image = 'rose.jpg' # your original file name
    
    destination_folder = u'C:\\photos\\flowers\\flower1\\crop\\'

    # FileOpen
    App.Do( Environment, 'FileOpen', {
            'FileList': [source_path + source_image], 
            'Folder': source_path, 
            })

    # SelectDocument
    App.Do( Environment, 'SelectDocument' )

    # Resize
    App.Do( Environment, 'Resize', {
            'AspectRatio': 0.997183, 
            'CurrentDimensionUnits': App.Constants.UnitsOfMeasure.Pixels, 
            'CurrentResolutionUnits': App.Constants.ResolutionUnits.PixelsPerIn, 
            'Height': size_height, 
            'MaintainAspectRatio': True, 
            'Resample': True, 
            'ResampleType': App.Constants.ResampleType.Bicubic, 
            'ResizeAllLayers': True, 
            'Resolution': 499, 
            'Width': size_width, 
            'SharpnessValue': 50, 
            'AdvancedMode': True, 
            'ResizeType': 0, 
            'OneSide_Type': 0, 
            'OneSide_LongWidth': 657, 
            'OneSide_ShortHeight': 655, 
            'OneSide_Unit': App.Constants.UnitsOfMeasure.Pixels, 
            'OneSide_Active': 0, 
            })

    # ResizeCanvas
    App.Do( Environment, 'ResizeCanvas', {
            'AspectRatio': 0.996016, 
            'FillColor': (9,7,10), 
            'HoriPlace': App.Constants.HorizontalType.Center, 
            'MaintainAspect': False, 
            'NewDimUnits': App.Constants.UnitsOfMeasure.Pixels, 
            'NewHeight': crop_height, 
            'NewWidth': crop_width, 
            'PlaceBottom': place_bottom, 
            'PlaceLeft': place_left, 
            'PlaceRight': place_right, 
            'PlaceTop': place_top, 
            'VertPlace': App.Constants.VerticalType.Center, 
            })


    # at this point, I prefer to copy and paste as new image
    # or copy-merged and paste as a new image
    # because I can conrol everything from the script editor (I use Notepad++)
    # plus, in the long run, it saves time    # Copy
    App.Do( Environment, 'Copy' )

    # CopyMerged >> used for copying multi-layer images
    # App.Do( Environment, 'CopyMerged' )

    # PasteGraphicAsNewImage
    App.Do( Environment, 'PasteGraphicAsNewImage' )

    # SelectDocument new image
    App.Do( Environment, 'SelectDocument' )

    name = App.ActiveDocument.Title

    # FileSaveAs
    App.Do( Environment, 'FileSaveAs', {
            'Encoding': {
                'JPG': {
                    'Variant': App.Constants.JpegFormat.Lossless, 
                    'CompressionFactor': 20, 
                    'ChromaSubSampling': App.Constants.ChromaSubSampling.YCC_1x1_1x1_1x1, 
                    'EXIF': True, 
                    'EmbedJPGICC': True
                    }
                }, 
            'FileName': destination_folder + name + '.jpg', 
            'FileFormat': App.Constants.FileFormat.JPG, 
            'FormatDesc': u'JPG JPEG ', 
            'WorkingMode': 0, 
            'DefaultProperties': []
            })

    # FileClose the new image
    App.Do( Environment, 'FileClose' )

    # SelectDocument the source_image
    App.Do( Environment, 'SelectDocument' )

    # FileClose the source_image
    App.Do( Environment, 'FileClose' )

    # SelectDocument
    App.Do( Environment, 'SelectDocument' )
```